# dayclick in fullcalendar not working

Tags: php, fullcalendar, yii2-advanced-app

Dayclick in fullcalendar is not working in my yii2 site. I have used following code. I can't get this code working.

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

       header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },

         ignoreTimezone:true,
         editable: true,

         events: $list,

         className: 'gcal-event',
         eventClick:function(event){
                       var x = event.id; 
                       document.cookie='id='+x+''; 
                       $('#cal-modal').modal('show');
                      }
        });


      $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
       dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
                 alert('Clicked on: ' + date.format());
                 $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
                 }
      });
});
```

Please take a look at my code and give suggestions.

Comment: any error showing?

Comment: No error is shown.

Comment: is the `alert('Clicked on: ' + date.format());` showing?

Comment: no, I can't get the click event working.

Comment: try putting the `dayClick` function inside the first `$('#calendar').fullCalendar({`

Comment: I tried that. Still not working

Comment: alert is turned off in JSBin. You shouldn't debug with alert because it stops code execution. While JSBin is a great tool for building quick samples, it makes debugging harder.

Answer (score 0):

Check this : https://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/dayClick/

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {

        if (allDay) {
            alert('Clicked on the entire day: ' + date);
        }else{
            alert('Clicked on the slot: ' + date);
        }

        alert('Coordinates: ' + jsEvent.pageX + ',' + jsEvent.pageY);

        alert('Current view: ' + view.name);

        // change the day's background color just for fun
        $(this).css('background-color', 'red');

    }
});
```